# Как в js сделать скролл на нужный мне radio button?

Tags: javascript

Есть рабочий js который смотрит отмечены ли все `radio` кнопки и выдает `alert`.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn1").on("click", function () {
        var count = 0;
        var questions = $("div.btn-group");
        questions.each(function () {
            if ($(this).find("input").filter('[type="radio"]').filter(":checked").length > 0) {
                count++;
            }
        });
        if (count >= questions.length) {
            alert("Все ок!");
        } else {
            $('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: $('.btn-group input[type="radio"]:not(:checked)').offset().top }, 500);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<form>
<div class="btn-group-wrap">
 <h4>1. Я часто не уверен в собственных решениях.</h4>
 <div class="btn-group"><br>
       <label class="btn btn-default">
                   <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="radio"> Нет
             </label>
             <label class="btn btn-default">
                     <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="radio"> Скорее нет, чем да
             </label> 
             <label class="btn btn-default">
                   <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="radio"> Скорее да, чем нет
             </label> 
             <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="radio"> Да
             </label>
 </div><hr>
 <h4>2. Иногда мне кажется, что никому нет до меня дела.</h4>
    <div class="btn-group"><br>
       <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="radio"> Нет
             </label> 
             <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="radio"> Скорее нет, чем да
             </label> 
             <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="radio"> Скорее да, чем нет
             </label> 
             <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="radio"> Да
             </label> 
      </div><hr>

 <h4>3. Часто, даже хорошо выспавшись, я с трудом заставляю себя встать с постели.</h4>
    <div class="btn-group"><br>
       <label class="btn btn-default">
                     <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="radio"/> Нет
             </label> 
             <label class="btn btn-default">
                     <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="radio"/> Скорее нет, чем да
             </label> 
             <label class="btn btn-default">
                     <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="radio"/> Скорее да, чем нет
             </label> 
             <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="radio"/> Да
             </label> 
      </div><hr>

 
 <h4>4. Я постоянно занят, и мне это нравится.</h4>
    <div class="btn-group"><br>
       <label class="btn btn-default">
                     <input type="radio" name="radio4" value="radio"/> Нет
             </label> 
             <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio4" value="radio"/> Скорее нет, чем да
             </label> 
             <label class="btn btn-default">
                   <input type="radio" name="radio4" value="radio"/> Скорее да, чем нет
             </label> 
             <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio4" value="radio"/> Да
             </label> 
      </div><hr>

  
 
 <h4>5. Часто я предпочитаю «плыть по течению».</h4>
    <div class="btn-group"><br>
       <label class="btn btn-default">
                     <input type="radio" name="radio5" value="radio"/> Скорее нет, чем да
             </label>  
             <label class="btn btn-default">
                     <input type="radio" name="radio5" value="radio"/> Скорее нет, чем да
             </label> 
             <label class="btn btn-default">
                     <input type="radio" name="radio5" value="radio"/> Скорее да, чем нет
             </label> 
             <label class="btn btn-default">
                     <input type="radio" name="radio5" value="radio"/> Да
             </label> 
      </div><hr>
      
      <h4>6. Я меняю свои планы в зависимости от об­стоятельств.</h4>
 <div class="btn-group"><br>
       <label class="btn btn-default">
                   <input type="radio" name="radio6" value="radio"> Нет
             </label>
             <label class="btn btn-default">
                     <input type="radio" name="radio6" value="radio"> Скорее нет, чем да
             </label> 
             <label class="btn btn-default">
                   <input type="radio" name="radio6" value="radio"> Скорее да, чем нет
             </label> 
             <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio6" value="radio"> Да
             </label>
 </div><hr>
 
 <h4>7. Меня раздражают события, из-за которых я вынужден менять свой распорядок дня.</h4>
 <div class="btn-group"><br>
       <label class="btn btn-default">
                   <input type="radio" name="radio7" value="radio"> Нет
             </label>
             <label class="btn btn-default">
                     <input type="radio" name="radio7" value="radio"> Скорее нет, чем да
             </label> 
             <label class="btn btn-default">
                   <input type="radio" name="radio7" value="radio"> Скорее да, чем нет
             </label> 
             <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio7" value="radio"> Да
             </label>
 </div><hr>
 
 <h4>8. Непредвиденные трудности порой сильно утомляют меня.</h4>
 <div class="btn-group"><br>
       <label class="btn btn-default">
                   <input type="radio" name="radio8" value="radio"> Нет
             </label>
             <label class="btn btn-default">
                     <input type="radio" name="radio8" value="radio"> Скорее нет, чем да
             </label> 
             <label class="btn btn-default">
                   <input type="radio" name="radio8" value="radio"> Скорее да, чем нет
             </label> 
             <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio8" value="radio"> Да
             </label>
 </div><hr>
 
 <h4>9. Я всегда контролирую ситуацию настоль­ко, насколько это необходимо.</h4>
 <div class="btn-group"><br>
       <label class="btn btn-default">
                   <input type="radio" name="radio9" value="radio"> Нет
             </label>
             <label class="btn btn-default">
                     <input type="radio" name="radio9" value="radio"> Скорее нет, чем да
             </label> 
             <label class="btn btn-default">
                   <input type="radio" name="radio9" value="radio"> Скорее да, чем нет
             </label> 
             <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input type="radio" name="radio9" value="radio"> Да
             </label>
 </div><hr>
 

<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="btn1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">>Получить результат</button>
</form>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Есть ли способ в `else` назначить таким образом, чтобы меня перебрасывало c эффектом анимации именно на тот `radio button`, который `:unchecked`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn1").on("click", function() {
    var count = 0;
    var questions = $("div.btn-group");
    questions.each(function() {
      if ($(this).find("input").filter('[type="radio"]').filter(":checked").length > 0) {
        count++;
        $(this).addClass('checked');
      }
    });
    if (count >= questions.length) {
      alert("Все ок!");
    } else {
      $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.btn-group').not('.checked').prev('h4').offset().top
      }, 500);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="btn-group-wrap">
    <h4>1. Я часто не уверен в собственных решениях.</h4>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <br>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="radio">Нет
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="radio">Скорее нет, чем да
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="radio">Скорее да, чем нет
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="radio">Да
      </label>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <h4>2. Иногда мне кажется, что никому нет до меня дела.</h4>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <br>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="radio">Нет
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="radio">Скорее нет, чем да
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="radio">Скорее да, чем нет
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="radio">Да
      </label>
    </div>
    <hr>

    <h4>3. Часто, даже хорошо выспавшись, я с трудом заставляю себя встать с постели.</h4>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <br>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="radio" />Нет
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="radio" />Скорее нет, чем да
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="radio" />Скорее да, чем нет
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="radio" />Да
      </label>
    </div>
    <hr>


    <h4>4. Я постоянно занят, и мне это нравится.</h4>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <br>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio4" value="radio" />Нет
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio4" value="radio" />Скорее нет, чем да
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio4" value="radio" />Скорее да, чем нет
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio4" value="radio" />Да
      </label>
    </div>
    <hr>



    <h4>5. Часто я предпочитаю «плыть по течению».</h4>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <br>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio5" value="radio" />Скорее нет, чем да
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio5" value="radio" />Скорее нет, чем да
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio5" value="radio" />Скорее да, чем нет
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio5" value="radio" />Да
      </label>
    </div>
    <hr>

    <h4>6. Я меняю свои планы в зависимости от об­стоятельств.</h4>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <br>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio6" value="radio">Нет
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio6" value="radio">Скорее нет, чем да
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio6" value="radio">Скорее да, чем нет
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio6" value="radio">Да
      </label>
    </div>
    <hr>

    <h4>7. Меня раздражают события, из-за которых я вынужден менять свой распорядок дня.</h4>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <br>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio7" value="radio">Нет
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio7" value="radio">Скорее нет, чем да
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio7" value="radio">Скорее да, чем нет
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio7" value="radio">Да
      </label>
    </div>
    <hr>

    <h4>8. Непредвиденные трудности порой сильно утомляют меня.</h4>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <br>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio8" value="radio">Нет
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio8" value="radio">Скорее нет, чем да
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio8" value="radio">Скорее да, чем нет
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio8" value="radio">Да
      </label>
    </div>
    <hr>

    <h4>9. Я всегда контролирую ситуацию настоль­ко, насколько это необходимо.</h4>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <br>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio9" value="radio">Нет
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio9" value="radio">Скорее нет, чем да
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio9" value="radio">Скорее да, чем нет
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="radio9" value="radio">Да
      </label>
    </div>
    <hr>


    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="btn1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">>Получить результат</button>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: xaja, ваш .animate перебрасывает на самый первый btn-group, а не на :uncheked. где я ошибся ?

Comment: @Niflungar, а как определяете где ошиблись?

Comment: Сделал update..

Comment: Спасибо xaja! Все работает.